# Invalid syntax in "for item in L" loop

Tags: python

I have a feeling I'm missing something pretty simple here but, in this one function:

```
def triplets(perimeter):

    triplets, n, a, b, c = 0  #number of triplets, a, b, c, sides of a triangle, n is used to calculate a triple
    L = primes(int(math.sqrt(perimeter)) #list of primes to divide the perimeter

    for item in L: #iterate through the list of primes
        if perimeter % item == 0: #check if a prime divides the perimeter
            n = perimeter / item
            a = n**2 - (n+1)**2 #http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pythagorean_triple
            b = 2n*(n+1)
            c = n**2 + n**2
            if a+b+c == perimeter: #check if it adds up to the perimeter of the triangle
                triplets = triplets + 1

    return triplets
```

I am getting the error:

```
    for item in L:
                 ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

For completeness my entire program looks like this:

```
import math

def primes(n): #get a list of primes below a number
    if n==2: return [2]
    elif n<2: return []
    s=range(3,n+1,2)
    mroot = n ** 0.5
    half=(n+1)/2-1
    i=0
    m=3
    while m <= mroot:
        if s[i]:
            j=(m*m-3)/2
            s[j]=0
            while j<half:
                s[j]=0
                j+=m
        i=i+1
        m=2*i+3
    return [2]+[x for x in s if x]

def triplets(perimeter):

    triplets, n, a, b, c = 0  #number of triplets, a, b, c, sides of a triangle, n is used to calculate a triple
    L = primes(int(math.sqrt(perimeter)) #list of primes to divide the perimeter

    for item in L: #iterate through the list of primes
        if perimeter % item == 0: #check if a prime divides the perimeter
            n = perimeter / item
            a = n**2 - (n+1)**2 #http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pythagorean_triple
            b = 2n*(n+1)
            c = n**2 + n**2
            if a+b+c == perimeter: #check if it adds up to the perimeter of the triangle
                triplets = triplets + 1

    return triplets

def solve():
    best = 0
    perimeter = 0
    for i in range(1, 1000):
        if triplets(i) > best:
            best = triplets(i)
            perimeter = i
    return perimeter

print solve()
```

I am using Python 2.7.1. I have a semicolon after the for loop, the `primes(n)` function works, I have a feeling it is probably something stupid but I can't figure out what it is that is causing this invalid syntax.

Comment: parenthesis in the `L =...` line

Answer (score 18, accepted):

You are missing a closing parenthesis on the line before:

```
      L = primes(int(math.sqrt(perimeter)) #list of primes to divide the perimeter
#               ^   ^         ^         ^^
#nesting count  1   2         3         21
```

See how we don't reach 0 in the "nesting count" below the line?

Comment: Shoot. I knew it was something simple. So embarrassed. Haha. Thanks.

Comment: Just would like to comment: I made two other mistakes (that I found out later): `b = 2n*(n+1)` should be `b = 2*n*(n+1)` also, I needed to initializes triplets, a, b, c, and n differently.

Answer (score 1):

You're missing a parenthesis:

```
L = primes(int(math.sqrt(perimeter)))
                                    ^
                                    |
                                 this one
```

This happens to me all the times, you just needed look at the line before.

Answer (score 0):

There is an error in the line before it:

```
L = primes(int(math.sqrt(perimeter))
```

You have 3 open parens, but only two closing parens.

Answer (score 0):

The error is in the line above - you're missing a close bracket:

```
L = primes(int(math.sqrt(perimeter)))
```